# Semantic react ui Popup close button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-react-ui's Popup component and I was wondering how to trigger close popup event by clicking a button inside the popup without using jquery.

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/#usage-controlled), you have to create a controlled Popup.
Create a component which nests the `Popup` component, and maintain a state in it:

```
class ControlledPopup extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };                  // state to control the state of popup
  }
  
  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  }
  
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Popup
          trigger={<button>click to open</button>}
          content={<button onClick={this.handleClose}>click to close</button>}
          on='click'
          open={this.state.isOpen}
          onOpen={this.handleOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add `onClose={this.handleClose}` to enable the default behavior of closing when clicking outside the menu.

Comment: Can I add multiple buttons inside content? I want to show a confirm and close buttons in popup

Comment: What if you have multiple popups on the same page? This solution would open them all unfortunately..

Comment: You have to namespace the state by having separate keys in state, i.e., `isPopup1Open`, `isPopup2Open`, and so on.

Comment: Note that the doc changed. Here is the updated version: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/#usage-controlled

Answer (score 1):

Here is the TS + React Hooks version of the above:

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';

import { Popup } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const ControlledPopup: FC = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Popup
            trigger={<button>click to open</button>}
            content={<button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>click to close</button>}
            on="click"
            open={isOpen}
            onOpen={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
        />
    );
};

export default ControlledPopup;
```